# Accessing users iTunes Library without MPMediaPickerController

Tags: ios, iphone, uitableview, mpmediapickercontroller

Is there another way to access the users `iTunes Library` than  [`MPMediaPickerController`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/MediaPlayer/Reference/MPMediaPickerController_ClassReference/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/cl/MPMediaPickerController)?

Can the `UITableView` which is used to present the `MPMediaPickerController` be customized?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Is there another way to access the users itunes library than MPMediaPickerController ?

Sure, there's `MPMediaQuery` to query the iPod library programmatically. Once you havwe the data, you can display it any way you want. See the [iPod Library Access Programming Guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Audio/Conceptual/iPodLibraryAccess_Guide/Introduction/Introduction.html).