# How can I access files outside app bundle in iPhone

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, cocoa-touch, audio

I want to create iPhone app that can play mp3 files that stored outside app bundle. The mp3 files that I want to access are stored in iPhone hard disk such as **mp3 files that stored in iTunes_Control folder**.

I want to retrieve these files from **iTunes_Control** folder in order to make a playlist and play them in my application without copy them into the application bundle. Do you have any idea how to solve this requirement?

Thank you very much.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Accessing users itunes library](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5221549/accessing-users-itunes-library)

Answer (score 6):

Due to sandboxing you may only access files of your own app bundle. As for the mp3files,  You can access mp3 you stored with iTunes. Check out this answer to find out how to do it. [Accessing users iTunes Library without MPMediaPickerController](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5221549/accessing-users-itunes-library/5222267#5222267)